# How to call Run() with parameters

Tags: batch-file, parameters, vbscript

I've got this working line of code in Windows Batch

```
start "" /wait /i "C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:NetBeans /wait "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\bin\netbeans64.exe"
```

I would like to run it via VBScript. But I don't know how to pass the path in parameter which has a space inside.

I came up with something like this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:NetBeans /wait "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\bin\netbeans64.exe"), 1, True
```

But there is an error:

> expected: ')'

Comment: Check stack overflow, they may know. There is also a way to call to copy ini files after the exe runs too.  Vb is very neat.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within a literal string, a single double-quote character is represented by two double-quote characters. So try the following instead:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe"" /box:NetBeans /wait ""C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\bin\netbeans64.exe""", 1, True
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 5):

I like to use the following system to embed quotes :

```
strCommand = Quotes("C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe") & _
         " /box:NetBeans /wait " &                            _
         Quotes("C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\bin\netbeans64.exe")

Function Quotes(ByVal strValue)
    Quotes = Chr(34) & strValue & Chr(34)
End Function
```

It's a lot easier to read.