# Convert command line code to vbs code

Tags: vbscript

I have a command line code with me.Can any one help to convert the line of code
to vbs.The line of code must be executed under oshell.Run command.(wher oshell is the object of WScript.Shell)

The command line code is as follows

```
 c:\programfiles x(86)\winscp>winscp.com /command "option batch abort" "option confirm off" "open ftps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@FTPSITE.COM:PORTNUMBER/" "put C:\MyFolder\ForSFTP\TestFile.txt /savefile/" "exit"
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript: How to call Run() with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025843/vbscript-how-to-call-run-with-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CreateObject` to create "WScript.Shell" object.

Use `""` to escape `"` inside a string.

Use the [help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to see other arguments of `Shell.Run` method.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "c:\program files x(86)\winscp\winscp.com /command ""option batch abort"" ""option confirm off"" ""open ftps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@FTPSITE.COM:PORTNUMBER/"" ""put C:\MyFolder\ForSFTP\TestFile.txt /savefile/"" ""exit""", 1, True
```