# How to escape blanks in path name - Windows Scripting

Tags: windows, wsh

I'm trying to run script below. The first program start up just fine but the second one with the blank spaces in the path name doesn't. How can this be resolved? Thanks.

```
    Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Shell.Run "cmd /n,C:\Windows\System32\", 4, False
    Shell.Run "sublime_text /n,C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\", 4, False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript: How to call Run() with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025843/vbscript-how-to-call-run-with-parameters)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by following link below. I rewrote the last statement with 3 double quotes.

[How to call Run() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025843/vbscript-how-to-call-run-with-parameters)

```
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "cmd /n,C:\Windows\System32\", 4, False
Shell.Run """C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe""", 4, False
```